# Error Retrieving information from server DF-DLA-26

Tags: android, reactjs, flutter, flutter-layout

Hi I recently launched my flutter app in PlayStore, but for some reason 2 person reported this error when trying to download the app, one being the client who is not actually techy. Is it app related or just playstore/device related?

Ive searched about this error and all it throws to me is to clear cache. I can download it to some device.

> My email works but for some reason any email other than mine produces this error
>
> Tried clearing google play store and services on a different phone with a different error but still the error appears and cant download the app

Comment: > "My email works but for some reason any email other than mine produces this error"

what error?

Comment: Hi @HarshvardhanJoshi Error Retrieving information from server DF-DLA-26